# Unity Vuforia Object Doesn't Show On Ground Plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I was trying to use Vuforia's Ground Plane feature following this tutorial, only putting a cube on a ground plane though.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O6VxnNRFyg&t=25s

First the DefaultPlaneIndicator prefab has to be manually dragged from Vuforia's prefabs into the Plane Finder object, unlike in the tutorial. I used this automatic mode but it doesn't work. Interactive mode doesn't work either.

When I test it in the Editor nothing pops up when camera shows the floor and I tap the screen. Same goes for when I test it on my phone (Mi 8 with latest MIUI and Android versions).

Here's a [screenshot of my work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzF0K.png)

Here are the [Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8gjL.png) when I test it on the Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone doesn't support AR core. that's why you are not seeing anything. Please try on phone with AR core support.